# display summary data from a typescript function in a workshop table

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I need to do some aggregation that is not supported in the pivot table widget.  I can do the aggregation in typescript and return the data in 3d aggregation object, but I need to show it in a table, not a graph.

How can I do this in workshop.  Looks like a 2d array is not supported, which is why I am using a 3d aggregation object as my return type.

I tried creating a 3d aggregation object, but I cannot find a workshop widget to display it as a table.

I looked at creating a 2d array, but that does not look like a valid return type for workshop function.

I thought about formatting the table as a html table string, but could not find a workshop widget that supports it, including the markdown widget.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Pivot Table widget does not currently support displaying function-backed information (e.g., a function backed column), so this is feature request that I hope we can tackle in the future.

As some alternative options, you could

1. consider having your function return a Markdown table and then displaying that in the Markdown widget or
2. use the Quiver Dashboard widget to embed a Pivot Table from Quiver, which may offer the additional aggregation options you need.

Comment: Any chance you could give a quick example of a table in a markdown?